# Ticker or sleep on retry for HTTP WAIT in for loop?

Tags: go, concurrency

I have a for loop that runs in a goroutine that's managed by a WaitGroup. The for loop makes an HTTP WAIT call, checks status on return, and will retry depending on status. I currently use a sleep for one second before the retry (the next iteration of the for loop), but am wondering if the proper idiomatic go would be to use a Ticker. Though, I'm not sure what this would look like unless I had some way to spawn a thread to run the HTTP WAIT request, manage that thread, and then check status of the HTTP WAIT on each Ticker interval. That just doesn't seem like the right call vs. just using a sleep that may or may not depending on the HTTP WAIT. More often than not, it should return before the 2min HTTP timeout, and if it runs for more than 3 retries, I want to kill the goroutine by exiting the loop and letting the goroutine complete.

What's the right way to do this in Go?

Answer (score 0):

The [retryablehttp](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-retryablehttp) package provides a familiar HTTP client interface with automatic retries and exponential backoff